# Email is not sending in cakephp 3.x in localhost

Tags: php, cakephp

Here I am trying to send the email from localhost.I have configured the smtp server setting in php.ini and sendmail.ini file as well.And my code changes are

app.php

```
  'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => '******',
            'password' => '********',
           // 'client' => null,
           // 'tls' => null,
        ],
    ],
'Email' => [
        'default' => [
            'transport' => 'default',
            'from' => '**********',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        ],
    ],
```

Controller code.

```
$email = new Email('default');
    try {
        $res = $email->from('*****@**.**')
              ->to(['*****@**.**' => 'My Website'])
              ->subject('Tsting')                   
              ->send("hiii this is for testing ");

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

    }
```

Comment: I have done some research they said mail will send from localhost too.. Can anybody please help me

Comment: What error/exception do you get when running this code?

Comment: Where is `localhost` defined?

Comment: Running your code worked for me on localhost. Are you including the email class at the top of your controller?

use Cake\Network\Email\Email;